# javascript key-value array from 2 sources

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

I got multiple strings in this format

```
var string1 = "01&foo&bar"
var string2 = "02&food&bark"
var string3 = "03&fool&bars"
```

and as a final result I want an array like this:

```
var module = [
    {"ID":01, "title":"foo", "description":"bar"},
    {"ID":02, "title":"food", "description":"bark"},
    {"ID":03, "title":"fool", "description":"bars"}
];
```

whats  special about my question is, that the Key-parts are not given in the source strings.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** methods.

```js
var string1 = "01&foo&bar";
var string2 = "02&food&bark";
var string3 = "03&fool&bars";
// put strings inside an array and iterate
var res = [string1, string2, string3].map(function(v) {
  // split string based on `&`
  var arr = v.split('&');
  // generate array element 
  return {
    ID: arr[0],
    title: arr[1],
    description: arr[2]
  };
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string1 = "01&foo&bar"

{"ID" : string1.split('&')[0],"title":string1.split('&')[1],"description":string1.split('&')[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the strings into an array like this:

`var strings = ["01&foo&bar", "02&food&bark", "03&fool&bars"];`

then you can iterate through the strings and split them on `&` like this:

```
var module = [];
for (var i in strings) {
  var parts = strings[i].split("&");
  module.push({"ID" : parts[0],
               "title" : parts[1],
               "description" : parts[2]});            
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.